# FlutterError - Provider<bbb> not found(after obfuscation) - how fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics, obfuscation

I have Flutter app for Android. I use provider in my app. For release mode I using obfuscation:

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate  --split-debug-info
```

In debug mode app working(without obfuscation). But in Crashlistycs I noticed the following error:

```
Provider._inheritedElementOf
io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError - Provider<bbb> not found for 
xcb
```

I don't use classes "bbb" or "xcb" in my app. I think this is result of obfuscation.

Also, this error is not very common (about 30) - that is, not all users have it. is there a way to exclude certain classes from the flutter obfuscation process?  didn't find anything about additional obfuscation settings for Flutter (something like proguard for Android)

any ideas - I will be grateful.

Comment: Do you upload debug info to crashlytics/sentry/whatever you use?

Comment: yes, I used firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app ....

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official Firebase / Crashlytics documentation:

> If your Flutter project uses the `--split-debug-info` flag (and, optionally, also the `--obfuscate` flag), additional steps are required to show readable stack traces for your apps.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter&hl=it#add-sdk

Comment: I uploaded debug symbols to crashlytics. I used firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app ....